# Prism NavigationService and MasterDetail on iOS, with Xamarin Forms

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism, master-detail

#### Description

I have this strange behaivor using NavigationService with my MasterDetail on **iOS**.
When I click the option in the menu calls a command from the ViewModel

```
private async void OnNavigateCommandExecuted(string path)
{
    //await NavigationService.NavigateAsync(path);
    await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("Navigation/ReadCodeInstructionPage"); //For example
}
```

There is a slight delay when the transition is made between the pages, and back button appears and then disappears.
**On Android works perfectly.**

Am I doing something wrong or is a bug?

#### Example

[image]

> 

Comment: https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Forms/tree/master/HamburgerMenu Did you follow  this ? The delay animation also exists in the official sample , but not the back button issue.

Comment: Yes, I based my code in that example. The weird thing is that in the example Works fine.

Comment: after upgrading to Prism 7 from 6 I can see a noticeable delay in navigating master-detail... I'm still trying to work around this, please do let me know if you find anything, even though this question is a little old

Comment: @Pedro https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/1402, you can look the response from brianlagunas.
An uggly workaround is hide the masterdetail before pushing the new page, that create a not delay effect.